# update-manager crash (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Tags: 14.04, update-manager, crash

For some reason the update-manager in Ubuntu 14.04 started to crash some weeks ago, and I'm not quite sure why (maybe I fiddled with something in the system I shouldn't have touched?) . When running `$update-manager` in a terminal, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 115, in  app.start_update()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/UpdateManager.py", line 212, in start_update
>       update_backend = get_backend(self, InstallBackend.ACTION_UPDATE)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/**init**.py", line 92, in get_backend
>       from .InstallBackendAptdaemon import InstallBackendAptdaemon
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/backend/InstallBackendAptdaemon.py", line 12, in 
>       from aptdaemon.gtk3widgets import (AptCancelButton,
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aptdaemon/gtk3widgets.py", line 42, in 
>       gi.require_version("Vte", "2.91")
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/**init**.py", line 83, in require_version
>        (namespace, version))
>
> ValueError: Namespace Vte not available for version 2.91

Does anyone know the reason for this crash, and (more importantly) how to solve the problem?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620401/update-manager-will-not-launch-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Duplicate of http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/6997/software-updates-and-software-updater-wont-start

Comment: Although there are duplicates, I think this is the best place for this question (i.e., if anything, others should be closed).

Answer (score 1):

I had an identical problem on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS "Trusty Tahr". My solution was

```
 sudo apt-get install gir1.2-vte-2.91
```

It appeared to fix this problem and `update-manager` launched. I then found I had an issue with [1404_HWE_EOL](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1404_HWE_EOL) and updated to 16 LTS.

Comment: This fixed my problem when i had purged python* from my ubuntu 16.04 xenial.
works like a charm!